# get averages of use and response with 'tidyverse' only for variables containing categorical levels

Tags: r, tidyverse, average, mean, tidy

I am trying to get:

1. average portal_use by practice name
2. average response rate by practice name

I am a bit confused as to how to get this when I have categorical variables. I want to achieve this only with 'tidyverse' library .

This is an example of data I have:

```
   A tibble: 17 x 2
   practice_name portal_use
   <chr>         <chr>     
 1 il            Yes       
 2 il            Yes       
 3 il            No        
 4 il            NA        
 5 ol            Yes       
 6 ol            Yes       
 7 ol            No        
 8 ol            No        
 9 ol            NA        
10 ol            NA        
11 al            Yes       
12 al            Yes       
13 al            Yes       
14 al            No        
15 al            NA        
16 al            NA        
17 al            NA
```

And with dput my data looks like:

```
  structure(list(practice_name = c("il", "il", "il", "il", "ol", 
    "ol", "ol", "ol", "ol", "ol", "al", "al", "al", "al", "al", "al", 
    "al"), portal_use = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", NA, "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
    "No", NA, NA, "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -17L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
   count(name, value) %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(n = n/sum(n))
```

Comment: above is the percentage - but I need averages of use per practice name - this means averages of those responding yes. and then secondly, I need the averages of responses for the portal use - having in mind I am having NA's

Comment: @GaB I am not sure what your expected is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
> table(df)
             portal_use
practice_name No Yes
           al  1   3
           il  1   2
           ol  2   2
```

or

```
> prop.table(table(df))
             portal_use
practice_name         No        Yes
           al 0.09090909 0.27272727
           il 0.09090909 0.18181818
           ol 0.18181818 0.18181818
```

Comment: are those percentages or averages? It seems those are percentages.

Comment: @GaB It is percentages. What average do you want? Could you show expected output?